# How to connect two tables in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm running a wateranalyzer and want to save the sensor-data in a MariaDB.
I split the data into 2 tables: one for the automated part and one table which stores data I enter manually:

Tables:

[image: Tables]

I'm having a hard time (with just basic knowledge about databases) to figure out how I can "bind" ID and DateTime from one table to the other one, so if manual data is added, ID is incremented by 1 and the actual Date and Time is set in DateTime.

I bet I can do this somehow in PHPmyadmin?

thanks for your time!

Comment: you can using triger

Answer (score 0):

using triger. this example for you.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER contacts_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON contacts FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   DECLARE vUser varchar(50);

   -- Find username of person performing the INSERT into table
   SELECT USER() INTO vUser;

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO contacts_audit
   ( contact_id,
     deleted_date,
     deleted_by)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.contact_id,
     SYSDATE(),
     vUser );

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it anything more complex than having an `ID` in `Wasser` that matches the other `ID`?  That is, first insert into `Luft`, then get the id and only then, `INSERT INTO Wasser...`.

(A Trigger seems unnecessarily complicated.)

Comment: I have no clue, really. That's why I asked here ;) I thought if I add another "id" column in the second table that it would act as it's own?

Comment: Search for techniques involving "1:many" and "hierarchical database".

Answer (score 0):

As Rick Suggested, you need to have an ID column in the second table that references ID in first table. Trigger is a better option if the process of getting the ID and inserting it along with other columns (pH, Redox...) into the second table is complicated.

Make ID in the second table as a foreign key to the ID in first table.